# Today Extension doesn't run on Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8, today-extension, ios10-today-widget

I am having issues running a Today Extension on Xcode 8. I created a brand new iOS app project then added a target for a Today Extension. When I run that scheme, the widget isn't listed in the choices available to me.

As a work around, I can see it if I run the application scheme but the widget NSLog output doesn't appear in the log

I didn't have the problem in previous versions of XCode.

Comment: xcode 8 is generally crap and full of bugs, wait for later version

Comment: @GAlexander can you reproduce the problem?